# Несколько json

Tags: json, php

Как например добавить сюда ещё:

> 'country' => 'UA', 'country_name' =>
> 'Украина','providers' => array('code'
> => 'Kyivstar', 'name' => 'Киевстар');

```
<?php
$json = array(
 'country' => 'RU', 
 'country_name' => 'Россия',
 'providers' => array(
  'code' => 'beeline',
  'name' => 'Билайн'
 )
);

json_encode($json)
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Странный вопрос, видимо выходные:-)

```
<?php
$json = array(
 array(
 'country' => 'RU', 
 'country_name' => 'Россия',
 'providers' => array(
  'code' => 'beeline',
  'name' => 'Билайн'
 )),
 array(...)
);

json_encode($json)
?>
```